# How to read this line?

Tags: reading

I'm not sure how to read this line:

> See the child. He is pale and thin, he wears a thin and ragged linen shirt. He stokes the scullery fire. **Outside lie dark turned fields with rags of snow and darker woods beyond that harbor yet a few last wolves.**

(From [*Blood Meridian: or The Evening Redness In The West* by Cormac McCarthy](https://genius.com/Cormac-mccarthy-blood-meridian-or-the-evening-redness-in-the-west-chap-1-annotated))

Is it something like this:

> Outside, lie dark turned fields, with...

Comment: Please could you add the source?

Comment: This passage is difficult to read on the first try.  The way it’s constructed is part of the author’s style.  Further description added as an answer.

Comment: @whiskeychief Thanks. I was really confused.

Comment: El.Do, don’t forget to please accept an answer (☑️) if you believe your question is answered.  Thanks for contributing and keep it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

> Outside lie dark turned fields with rags of snow and darker woods beyond that harbor yet a few last wolves.

This sentence from Cormac McCarthy, *Blood Meridian*, 1985, is in two parts:

> A is true **and** B is true.

This is usually written with a comma.

> A is true, **and** B is true.

## Part A

“Lie” is the plural form because the sentence says:

> Outside lie Fields.

Or

> Fields are outside,  with rags of snow.

### Sidebar

> Notice the phrase **{dark turned fields}**.  It is normal to write "dark-turned fields", with a hyphen.  This is being done **intentionally** by the author.
>
> Without the hyphen, you can interpret this as meaning
>
> > 1) "fields that have become dark",
>
> or possibly
>
> > 2) "fields, which are dark, that have been 'turned over' by the farmer's machinery."
>
> Most readers would choose (1), but the fact that there is potential for **ambiguity**, caused by missing punctuation, is part of the author's style.  More on this in a moment.

## Part B

> Darker woods beyond that harbor yet a few last wolves.

Means

> Darker woods — (which are beyond those fields) — harbor yet a few last wolves.

Which means

> - Woods (which are darker than the fields),
> - and
> - which are farther away (than the fields,)
> - **contain**
> - {a few final wolves}
> - **even now.**

**Yet** means <sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/yet))</sup> “even now” or “still” or “continuing up until this moment.”

## Summing up

> Snowy fields are outside. Woods are beyond the fields, which still contain some wolves.

This sentence is intended to be very dense (packed with meaning).  The author has omitted at least one comma, quite intentionally.   See also his book “The Road” which omits many capital letters and tons of punctuation.   This is done for artistic reasons, similar to poetry.

As always with poetry, your interpretation may vary.

Comment: Wow Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase the sentence like this:

> Outside lie
>   dark turned fields, with rags of snow
>   and
>   darker woods beyond, that harbor yet a few last wolves.

Comment: Thank you Vane. Sorry i can't vote for your answer I dont have enough rep.one more question Is it only me or it is actually hard to read even for english speakers?

Comment: You can **accept** the right/best answer after a time limit.

Comment: Is it easy? I did have to think about where the "rags of snow" phrase belongs, and, whether **harbor** is a noun or a verb (it's a verb). There was some doubt at first whether "beyond that harbor" is a phrase - but it isn't, it's "harbor wolves".